# OOP / Typescript - is it possible to optimize code when class constructor has an interfaced object as param?

Tags: oop, angular, typescript

I'm new to typescript and my code has many repetitions of references (data1, data2, data3...).

```
export interface ProjectInterface{
  data1: string;
  data2: string;
  data3: number;
}

export class Project {
  data1: string;
  data2: string;
  data3: number;

  constructor(obj: ProjectInterface) {
    this.data1 = obj.data1;
    this.data2 = obj.data2;
    this.data3 = obj.data3;
  }
}
```

I know i could pass data1, data2... inside constructor but it's not handy when you have a lot of params.

Is there a clean workaround to keep the Interface has single entry point for references?

Comment: So you'd like to automatize property initialization in the constructor? I wouldn't necessarily call this an _optimization_, more like a semantic refinement.

Comment: yes i'd like to avoid repeating variables declarations in Project Class and automatize the initialization

Comment: Why don't you declare a property `data` of type `ProjectInterface` in the `Project` class, and simply go for `this.data = obj` ? Using `Object.assign` it is also possible to introduce some flexibility between the data injected and those held by the Class instance.

Comment: well then i'll have  an indirect access to properties like Project.data.property... i'd like to follow best practice and I was thinking some special syntax like implements, extends, etc. could help achieving that or was made for it.

Answer (score 2):

> i'd like to avoid repeating variables declarations in Project Class and automatize the initialization

While this certainly won't cut it in *all* circumstances, in your case you could use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to iterate over own properties of `obj`, while also performing some basic type-checking:

```
constructor(obj: ProjectInterface) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(key) && typeof this[key] == typeof obj[key]) {
            this[key] = obj[key];
        }
    });
}
```

This however requires that you also initialize your properties to a sensible default value, as `hasOwnProperty` will return false otherwise.

*Note the [ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) that preserves the correct lexical scope of `this`.*

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about something like that. But does it mean i don't have to declare variables data1,data2.. in the Class Project? looks like cheating a bit :)

Comment: Unfortunately, you have to. And you also have to initialize them to a default value (so that `hasOwnProperty` can return true), I forgot to include this in the answer.